# paper-dialog: How to properly set backdrop overlay for stacked dialog

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How do I set multiple backdrops for stacked paper dialogs?

Only the first dialog shows a backdrop. The second dialog doesn't show one
and I have set `with-backdrop` on both of them. How do I overlay the first dialog when the second dialog opens because I don't want the first dialog to be clickable when the second dialog opens?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not possible at the moment, but they seem to be working on it. See https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior/issues/124